# Binding Foreground from ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a binding problem with WindowsPhone 8 and a ControlTemplate.
Here is an example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="Red" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="123"/>
    </Button.Content>
<Button>
```

I would like to use in my Button.Content the foreground "Red" I defined in the ContentContainer. But nothing works...
The goal is to change the ContentContainer foreground in a VisualState in my Style. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
<Button Content="123"/>
```

Instead of putting a TextBlock.

However if you want to keep the TextBlock anyway, the you should do :

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    red
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: This was a minimum example. My real button content is more complex. When I define the foreground in a own style I cant changed the foreground in a visualstate

Comment: Then you should post your real code so we can understand your case

Answer (score 0):

Managed to pull this off with a behavior. It's a pretty complicated solution, 
but it's the only one i found working :

First, some Util stuff :

```
public static class IEnumerableExt
{
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source.Count() > 0)
            return source.ElementAt(0);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

and ...

```
public static class DependencyObjectExt
{
        public static DependencyObject GetChild(this DependencyObject @this, int childIndex)
        {
            return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(@this, childIndex);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildren(this DependencyObject @this)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(@this); i++)
            {
                yield return @this.GetChild(i);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildrenOfType<T>(this DependencyObject @this) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            foreach(var child in @this.GetChildren())
            {
                if(child is T)
                {
                    yield return child as T;
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> FindDescendantsOfType<T>(this DependencyObject @this) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            IEnumerable<T> result = Enumerable.Empty<T>();

            foreach(var child in @this.GetChildren())
            {
                if(child is T)
                {
                    result = result.Concat(child.ToEnumerable().Cast<T>());
                }
                result = result.Concat(child.FindDescendantsOfType<T>());
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

Now, let's define a behavior that does the binding :

```
public class ContentControlForegroundBindingBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{
    public static DependencyProperty ParentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Parent", typeof(Control),
            typeof(ContentControlForegroundBindingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Control Parent
    {
        get { return (Control)this.GetValue(ParentProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ParentProperty, value); }
    }


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (Parent == null) return;

            var control = AssociatedObject as Control;
            if (control == null) return;


            var contentControl = Parent.FindDescendantsOfType<ContentControl>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (contentControl == null) return;

            control.SetBinding(Control.ForegroundProperty, new Binding()
            {
                NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true,
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                BindsDirectlyToSource = true,
                Path = new PropertyPath(Control.ForegroundProperty),
                Source = contentControl
            });
        };
    }
}
```

What this behavior does is bind the control's foreground to the foreground of the ContentControl found in the template of the specified parent. 
This is how you use it (in xaml):

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
        xmlns:behaviors=" ---------- Your Behaviors Namespace ---------"

<Button x:Name="SomeName"
                Width="125"
                Height="30"
                Click="OnButtonClick"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="50,54,0,0">
            <Button.Content>
                <controls:IconText Icon="SomeIcon.png"
                                   Text="SomeText">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:ContentControlForegroundBindingBehavior Parent="{Binding ElementName=SomeName}"/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </controls:IconText>
            </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and Windows phone doesn't exist anymore.  I arrived here looking for a solution for WPF .NET, and didn't find a solution at the time.

Now that I've worked out a solution (for WPF .NET at least) I'm posting it here in case anyone else arrives here looking for inspiration the same way I did.

The solution is to use `TextElement`:

- Set `TextElement.Foreground` on the `ContentControl`
- Use `TemplateBinding` on the `Foreground` of the content.

Now the foreground colour is bound to the ContentControl's content from the ContentControl.

Using the OP's code as an example:

````
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" TextElement.Foreground="Red" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="123" Foreground="{TemplateBinding TextElement.Foreground}"/>
    </Button.Content>
<Button>```
````